# AFK открытие ссылок в браузере

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Мне необходима программа на питоне, которая будет из списка ссылок брать их поочереди и открывать в хроме.
есть вот такой код

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
def ex(links:list):
    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
a=[r"https://vk.com/feed",r"https://vk.com/feed",r"https://vk.com/feed"] 
ex(a)
driver.quit()
```

можете помочь отредоктировать чтобы работал
Выдаёт это

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/саша/Desktop/прога для теста кодов.py", line 1420, in <module>
builtins.FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/саша/Desktop/прога для теста кодов.py", line 2, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':
  File "C:\Users\саша\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\саша\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Так в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: добавил в текст условия

Comment: `'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH`, либо в переменные пути в PATH добавьте папку с chromedriver, либо путь с ним передавайте в `webdriver.Chrome`

Answer (score 0):

У вас не скачан `WebDriver` для его скачки зайдите на этот сайт: chrome://version/
Там же в самом верху вы увидете версию хрома и скачайте для вашей версии с [этого](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) сайта веб драйвер и засуньте его в папку с вашим скриптом.